# DHT22 bad readings on long rj45 cable

Tags: sensor, raspberry-pi, temperature, wire, rj45

Duplicate of https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/91781/dht22-bad-readings-on-long-cable, I figured there is chances people here have a solution for me.

Hi,

I'm preparing a setup with a long wire separating the sensors and the rpi. Wire is a cat6 RJ45 (ethernet) cable of 100ft (30m), that i'm using 6/8 wires. I randomly choose the wires, I figured as long as I take the same one at the other end, it should work. And it does, for the most part.

I've drawn my wiring to fitzing to explain it. See below. Some notes to take into consideration:

- For the RJ45 in the drawing, assume the white wire is partially colored of the closest wire on it's left. For exemple, the first wire is orange, and the second one is white-orange.
- For the resistor, horizontal ones are 10k and vertical ones are 1k.
- white-green and white-blue are not used, so i merged them on one end and put them to GND on the other end. Before doing that, I had interference between IRLed and button switches

[image: fritzing schema]
[image: schematics]

DHT22 readings are done in python, every minutes, using Adafruit_Python_DHT 1.4.0.
Exact code for DHT22 in this public repo: https://github.com/Ericmas001/hq-dht22-reader-docker/blob/master/exec/hq_dht22_reader.py

My problem is:
**DHT22 readings are 99% wrong. I'm reading 10.3°C (50°F) and 3288.7% humidity most of the time. Correct readings would be around 24°C (75°F) and 21% humidity.** Funny enough, I get correct reading somethign like twice an hour.

Currently, it's a 100ft (30m) cable but it's only as a proof of concept, PI and sensors are really no more then 10ft (3m) appart.

I've tried switching wires (to rule out that the problem was bad wiring within the RJ45) but result is always the same.

I've also tried using a 10ft (3m) jumper wire for the yellow wire (bypassing RJ45) and then, everything works fine.

So the problem seems to be because of the length of the wire.

I've done some research, and found out that there was similar problems for other people with the library

- https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code/issues/49
- https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT/pull/6

Unfortunately, those problem have all been resolved with recent 1.4.0 release, that I happen to be using in my setup.

**Does somebody knows how to resolve my issue. ?**

Also, you can assume this:

- Electric & electronic knowledge are very limited on my part. I'm learning using the internet and doing this as a hobby.
- I would prefer if solution is on the pi-side of the RJ45, since the sensor-side would be in the wall
- For the proof of concept, RJ45 and jumperwire are twisted together with wire caps.

[image]

Thanks, have a nice day !

Comment: Have you thought about using a remote microcontroller (Arduino, ESP32, ESP8266 or Wemos) with the sensor so that you don't exceed the spec'd range for the DHT22. If you use an ESPxx or Wemos it can connect with WiFi (only requirement is power at the remote end). You could even run your Raspberry as an access point for that.

Comment: If that's not possible you're going to have to test whether adding some noise suppressing capacitors at the Raspberry end of the long wire will clean up the signal from the DHT22 to make it reliable.

Comment: I'm not familiar with capacitors. Where would I put it on the wiring schema, and what would be the correct µF to use for my use case ?

Comment: Probably something like a 100nF capacitor between Vcc and GND. The idea is to stop the cable getting an AC voltage or acting as a radio antenna. You may want to do the same on the blanked out pairs and the pair you're using for the IR LED.

Comment: would this schema represent what you are saying ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3kiV.png

Comment: Not quite. It needs to be between the 5V line and the GND line that go to your DHT22.

Comment: Hmm. I don't understand, this is what i've tried to do, i've put one in the bottom right corner between 5V and GND of the DHT22, another one on the bottom left corner between 5V and GPIO of the IR LED, and one right in the middle between the 2 unused wired, that I thought you meant by "blanked out pairs"

Comment: One end on the orange wire. The other on the brown/white wire.

Comment: While the wiring setup is nice to show how a mess this is to wire up on breadboard, it's really hard to follow. Please also supply a schematic.

Comment: If you have the controller and sensor 3m apart and have 30m of wire to test, you may wish to spread the wire as much as possible for testing rather than having it be a coil on the floor.  The more it runs parallel to itself, the more stray inductance/capacitance you'll have to deal with.  In your use case it will probably be spread out full length anyway.  Often when a system requires arbitrarily long wire for sensors and such (seismic, oil work, industrial), the equipment is designed to use current mode communication rather than voltage mode.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've added schematics, I hope I got it right.

Comment: @KH you're right, during test i'm using a rolled 30m cable, but it will probably be spread out 20m when final. I will try spreading it out to better represent my use case, thanks !

Comment: @ericmas001 that schematic is well-done! Thanks!

Comment: Try different software, e.g. my http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#pdif2_DHTXXD (requires the pigpio daemon to be running, `sudo pigpiod`) I guess you are pushing the limits with the line length, however the software you are using is unreliable.

Comment: You could always try wiring the DHT22 in accordance with the manufacturers data sheet rather than inventing something without a pullup. It is probably unrealistic to expect it to work over this distance.

Answer (score 3):

Your sensor isn't meant to drive meters of cabling. That's simply not what it was designed for.

The idea to use Cat6 cabling is good, and I can see that it comes from the realization that ethernet over such cable works over long distances, too.

However, in ethernet, the twisted pairs of the signal lines are driven *differentially* (i.e. the current on one conductor is the opposite of that on the other, and at the receiving end, the *difference* between potentials is evaluated), and great care is taken to ensure the signal is robustly read and reconstructed.

Your circuitry has no measures whatsoever to fulfill the same role, so it simply doesn't work over a long distance of cabling, where you simply lose a lot of voltage to ohmic drop over distance, where you get the full length as antenna or secondary winding to a parasitic transformer with the power grid, and, most importantly here, where you take no steps to help the transmitter drive the capacitive and inductive load that the long wire represents.

For this to work, you'd need to change a few things:

- long runs of twisted pair really aren't good for low-voltage power transfer. Use transformers to step up your voltage at the feeding end, and step down at the receiving end.
- You'll need single-ended-to-differential conversion at the sensor end, and the opposite at the receiver end.
- You'll need to match the impedances.
- Not quite sure what the voltage divider in the sensor's data line does – but it does look to me like unnecesary load to the sensor. However, this will be obsolete by itself when you use the differential transceivers
- I don't know what speeds you need from the IR transmitter – but it was a good idea to use *something* to increase the drive strength of your Pi. However, instead of using a transistor at the transmitting end only, you'll want a schmitt-trigger buffer + drive transistor at the receiving end, or go for differential transceiver  + driving transistor right away
- This all considered, it's usually simpler to go and have a small microcontroller at one end of such a long line that does all the local interfacing, and only needs a *single* link over the long distance. If you go that route, you could *probably* even just use I²C instead of differential transceivers; low-speed I²C is relatively robust, and all non-least-cost microcontrollers come with I²C masters integrated, and the Pi can also act as I²C device; there's even kernel drivers.
- If you want to try I²C: there's actually sensors other than the slightly underdocumented DHT22 (where do people even find these things?!) that speak I²C themselves ([example temperature sensor](https://www2.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Silicon-Labs/SI7060-B-01-IV?qs=sGAEpiMZZMucenltShoSnsfH0dZNrEBAvz6sBugUk0eO7j7cB9ES9Q%3d%3d), [example humidity + temperature sensor](https://www2.mouser.com/Sensors/Environmental-Sensors/Board-Mount-Humidity-Sensors/_/N-axfmy/?Ns=Pricing|0)). That would save you quite a bit of trouble, as you could, without any further ado (actually: maybe a pull-up resistor) attach that thing to the Pi.
- If you actually want to do it like the "big kids": Industrial sensors typically are just supplied with a constant current (somewhere in the 4–20 mA range), and you'd read out the value by the voltage drop across sensor + cabling. Current loops are insensitive to cabling resistance.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I will look into everything you just said see what I can implement. Also, you never mentionned capacitors. I've seen them used in different scenarios close to mine, and some suggested on the other thread that it could help me. Could it ?  For the voltage divider on the sensor, i'm not sure either, this was my last attempt to make it work, the original wiring was only the 10K resistor, with no 1K->GND.

Comment: About I²C, i've read a little and i'm confused. You talk about a single link, but is'nt it  3 wires (GND, SDA, SCL) ? And were you suggesting I replace ALL the setup by placing a micro controller on the sensor-side (ex: arduino nano) and then communicating to the pi, or replacing only the DHT22 part of the setup ? If it's all, i'm confused since the pi would be the communication trigger for the IR and the DHT, but the switch on the sensor side would be another communication trigger, would it still work ?

Comment: @ericmas001 yep, "hide" all the remote things behind the microcontroller. You're right, the master would typically have to poll or you'd need another interrupt line.

Comment: Actually @joan 's PIGPIO library can be set to use an additional arbitrary pair of GPIO pins to provide a second I²C bus SCL/SDA wires which can be set to run at a slower clock rate - and be thus more resistant to timing errors and other effects from driving ***long-distance*** buses, whilst retaining the existing bus for local (to the RPi) stuff. Also, transceiver devices, such as the P82B715PN are specifically designed to send and receive I²C over longer distances - they provide the grunt needed to drive the longer lines (and the terminating resistors at the ends to damp down reflections)...

Comment: See also: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/109631/124900 https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/106265/maximum-i2c-bus-length !

Answer (score 0):

Raspberry Pi GPIO should register 3.3V for a logic 1.  Assuming the impedence looking into Pin22 GPIO 25 is infinite, Pin 12's voltage is a voltage divider.

1/11 or 1K/(1K+10K) of 5V = 5/11 = 0.45V << 3.3V (yikes!).  Choose R2 (pull down resistor) that provides 3.3 volts and not 5/11 = 0.45V

Seek: R1/(R1+R2) = 2/3

If we keep R2 = 10K,  then change R1= 20K Ohms

This analysis does not take into the account the voltage drop caused by the length of the CAT5  or similar cable (RJ45 is the spec for the end of an 8 wire data cable).  That being said cable voltage resistance is 1000X less than 10K, then it becomes negligible

[image]

Comment: Hi, i'm trying to make sense of what you said and i'm pretty sure I understand, the only thing that makes less sense to me is why you are specific about pin 12 having a voltage divider and why is it relevant here (since pin22 and pin36 have the exact same divider and pin12 is no more linked to the DHT22 than pin36). Forgetting about this confusion, I got that if I change all my R1 to 2K and all my R2 to 1K, i would have 3.3V instead of 0.45V on my 3 "data" pins, and that would probably eliminate my problem