# How to model I2C Bus in LTSpice?

Tags: i2c, ltspice, modeling

I want to model a single one master and two I2C Slaves on a bus. I want to determine how long I can make the I2C Trace to the last/second slave.

How to model the length of the I2C Bus in LTSpice? Should I be using a transmission line model?

Comment: This is an unusual goal for a simulation. For a more global picture of the problem, what bus length do you hope to achieve?

Comment: Probably this post may be of help, http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/106265/maximum-i2c-bus-length

Answer (score 1):

The length of the I<sup>2</sup>C bus manifests itself as capacitance, and you can model it as a lumped capacitor.  The I<sup>2</sup>C bus (assuming typical short distances which it's intended for) is way to slow to be concerned with transmission line model.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've got a ground plane with a capacitance which the trace works against,  The length of the trace manifests itself as inductance, so if you have a problem with delay you should tune it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to design your own I2C receivers and want to see now reflections might affect your sampling point, use of transmission line model is always useful and educational. For a fast mode (up to 3.4MHz) the reflections might chew up a significant portion of bit time.