# Limits to I2C switching multiple RFID/NFC readers with Raspberry Pi and I2C switch

Tags: switches, raspberry-pi, i2c, multiplexer, rfid

I am trying to set up an assembly line scenario where an item with and RFID tag is slid across an assembly line to different stations on a table.

In the image below you can see ID tags A and B as they move across different stations, and are placed over the sensors. The Pi will then send the tag ID and station location over WiFi.

[image]

I was hoping to use a number of [Raspberry Pi's and PN532 NFC/RFID](https://blog.stigok.com/2017/10/12/setting-up-a-pn532-nfc-module-on-a-raspberry-pi-using-i2c.html) modules that have both I2C or SPI capabilities.

If I use an I2C switch such as the ([TCA9548](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tca9548a.pdf?ts=1663023435934&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTCA9548A%253FkeyMatch%253DTCA9548A%2526tisearch%253Dsearch-everything%2526usecase%253DGPN)) could I read up to 8 sensors constantly with one Pi? If I wanted 16 stations with 2 I2C channels would this be possible with one Pi?

Furthermore, if I were to bit-bang I2C, or added further I2C switches, what becomes the limiting factor for the number of stations? Is it simply the Pi's/I2C max. clock rate to scan time for all stations?

For example, with a max. I2C clock of 400 kHz and each I2C packet being a max of ~32 bytes, is it ~80 μs per packet? And then 4 potential packets per scan and 16 sensors - I could cycle between all 16 every ~5 ms or so?

Comment: How far apart are the stations? I2C [is not well suited to long cables](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/106265/maximum-i2c-bus-length) and having multiple sensors on the bus will compound this problem.

Comment: I see.  Each station is about 1m. So the ends might be up to 10m away. I see from the thread that isn't recommended, but if I used some sort of buffer like this -https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/P82B96.pdf - Would it be ok?